# Context of this is messed up - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

Can you take a look at my code? I'm aware that the problem has to do with the context of this, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, related to the getLocationInfo function. I put a bind statement in the constructor function, but I also wrote the function definition with an arrow function (which I thought had implicit binding?). If I comment out the bind statement, I get 'getLocationInfo is not defined'. If I write out the function like ...

```
getLocationInfo(position){
    *insert function*
}
```

...  I get an unexpected token error, but all the curly brackets properly close.

Any guidance is appreciated... please see code below.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
     this.state = {
      fahrenheit: "",
      celsius: "",
      image: "",
      description: "",
      location: ""
     }
     this.getLocationInfo = this.getLocationInfo.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(getLocationInfo);
     } else { 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
     }

   getLocationInfo = (position) => {
         axios.get(`http request info`)
            .then(response => {
               this.setState({
                 description: response.data.weather[0].description,
                 fahrenheit: response.data.main.temp,
                 image: response.data.weather[0].icon,
                 location: response.data.main.name
              })
          })
      }
  }
```

Comment: Try `..getCurrentPosition(this.getLocationInfo);`.

Comment: You need to use the class method.. aka `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getLocationInfo)` ... Also you aren't using the position in the callback, why use navigator at all then?

Comment: Looks like you may be missing the closing brace on `componentDidMount`, so `getLocationInfo` is actually being defined within the body of `componentDidMount`